# Sublime text 2 in Ubuntu for debugging Rails applications

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sublimetext2

Recently I started using Sublime Text 2 for Rails application and I found it is really great. Then I needed to debug a method. I just put `debugger` in a method and nothing happened. By the way, I'm using passenger.

Then I installed `pry_debug` and also put a `binding.pry` keyword and there was no result either. No breaking. Now in `Gemfile` I have `pry_debug` and `debugger` gems.

So can I debug Rails applications in Sublime text 2? Especially using `pry_debug` gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not use `ruby-debug` trough IDE, well at least not with Sublime Text 2. Put following code in place. Assuming you have installed `ruby-debug` gem.

```
require 'ruby-debug'
...
debugger
...
```

And when you start the server you will have debug console from that break point (*debugger* line of code). From there you can use n (next), c (continue), to navigate trough the code or my favorite `irb` to change it in run time. This is old [screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug) but debugger still works the same way.

If you really want IDE debugging you can look into Rad on Rails (official support for Ruby 1.8.x I think) but trust me, that is more trouble than it is worth. Stick to Sublime Text 2 since it is awesome!

Comment: Regardless, you cannot do it trough sublime down-vote all you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Ruby Debugger for sublime,
Its a plugin for sublime the makes sublime to interactive debugger for ruby.